# ZF2 form's CSRF validates even with invalid values

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2, csrf

I have several forms that use the CSRF input. For example, in the constructor of my form, it looks like this:

```
    $this->add(array (
        'name' => 'csrf',
        'type' => 'Csrf',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'csrf'
        )
    ));
```

Just for kicks, I tried using Firebug to change the token value of the CSRF input and submitting the form, just to see what would happen. The result: it still validated. I even dumped the $_POST data to confirm that the invalid token was being submitted. What's more, I tried setting the timeout to 10 seconds, and the same thing happened: the form seemed to be ignoring the CSRF input and validating the form whether it was OK or not. The code is as follows:

```
    $this->add(array (
        'name' => 'csrf',
        'type' => 'Csrf',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'csrf'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'csrf_options' => array(
                'timeout' => 10
            )
        )
    ));
```

I even tried adding a filter for the CSRF element to the form's input filter, but again, it still passed when it bloody well shouldn't have.

Is there something else I should be doing here that I'm not? I don't want to add this to my form if it's not going to actually do anything.

EDIT: Here's a [link](http://pastie.org/9748405) to the code for my form and my controller action. Note that, while the form's method getInputFilter has validators for csrf, sex, and role, the result is the same without them.

Comment: That sounds weird. Are you 100% sure the form is validated? Could u check for form error messages within your controller or view file with $form->getMessages()?

Comment: It is weird. When checking in the browser, it validates just fine no matter what the csrf value is. Ditto in my unit tests: if I alter the csrf value in there, it sails on through.

Comment: Something else odd: my tests also pass if I add invalid values for either my Select or Radio elements...

Comment: Are you by chance use a zf2 development release or are you using a stable version?

Comment: Can you add your view to the pastebin aswell, I can't find anything within your Controller or Form and InputFilter. What you can try is to move the inputFilterSpecifications to a new file `UserInputFilter` and set it onto your form within your controller with `$form->setInputFilter(new UserFilter)` or use `getServiceLocator()` in order to retrieve the filter. What else you can check is what your inputfilter receives. Have a look at `$form->getInputFilter()->getRawValues()` to see what your `InputFilter` received.

Comment: I think you may have helped me solve the problem. I'm using [this module](http://neilime.github.io/zf2-twb-bundle/index.html) to render my forms. If I render them manually, the csrf will reject invalid values. Now to get a hold of the creator and ask if he knows of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the documentation a bit nore, I somehow stumbled across something that made me think. So I tried adding the following code to the getInputFilter method:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(
    array(
        'name' => 'csrf',
        'validators' => array (
            array(
                'name' => 'csrf'
            )
        )
)));
```

Call me crazy, but does this mean that the getInputFilter method clears out the pre-existing validators on elements like csrf, select, and radio?

Comment: did you find answer of question you asked in your answer?i have same question

Comment: No. Then again, I haven't really been looking. For now, I've just been setting the validator manually, and it works just fine.

Comment: here is answer of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778339/zf2-captcha-validation-ignored-when-using-an-input-filter